# Xamarin Xcode couldn't be found

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I just updated my MacOS to 12.4 and installed Xcode 13.1 but when I try to connect from my PC using VS2022 I  get nothing. In the Xamarin output window I get this message  Xcode couldn't be found so I am not sure what I need to do to get this running?

```
Broker 17.2.0.175 started successfully
Successfully connected to Local Broker
Starting IDB Local Agent...
Checking IDB.Local 17.2.0.175 installation...
Starting IDB.Local 17.2.0.175 in port 51028...
IDB.Local 17.2.0.175 started successfully
Successfully started IDB Local Agent
iTunes has not been found. Please ensure to have a valid iTunes installation in order to communicate with Apple devices in Windows
Checking host configuration for connecting to 'User Support - MacBook Pro'...
Checking SSH configuration...
Current SSH Key File: C:\Users\mcdevitt\AppData\Local\Xamarin\MonoTouch\id_rsa.pub
Initializing environment...
Checking available disk space...
Checking Mono installation...
Checking Xamarin iOS installation...
Checking host configuration for connecting to 'User Support - MacBook Pro'...
Host 'User Support - MacBook Pro' is configured correctly
Starting connection to 'User Support - MacBook Pro'...
Checking Broker 17.2.0.175 installation...
Installing Broker 17.2.0.175...
Uploading Broker.zip (160/1533 KB) 10%...
Uploading Broker.zip (320/1533 KB) 20%...
Uploading Broker.zip (464/1533 KB) 30%...
Uploading Broker.zip (624/1533 KB) 40%...
Uploading Broker.zip (768/1533 KB) 50%...
Uploading Broker.zip (928/1533 KB) 60%...
Uploading Broker.zip (1088/1533 KB) 70%...
Uploading Broker.zip (1232/1533 KB) 80%...
Uploading Broker.zip (1392/1533 KB) 90%...
Uploaded Broker.zip 100%
Starting Broker 17.2.0.175 in port 59780...
Broker 17.2.0.175 started successfully
Starting connection to 'User Support - MacBook Pro'...
SSH connection to 'User Support - MacBook Pro' has been established...
Starting registered Agents: IDB 17.2.0.175...
Starting IDB 17.2.0.175...
Checking IDB 17.2.0.175 installation...
Installing IDB 17.2.0.175...
Uploading IDB.zip (1552/15404 KB) 10%...
Uploading IDB.zip (3088/15404 KB) 20%...
Uploading IDB.zip (4624/15404 KB) 30%...
Uploading IDB.zip (6176/15404 KB) 40%...
Uploading IDB.zip (7712/15404 KB) 50%...
Uploading IDB.zip (9248/15404 KB) 60%...
Uploading IDB.zip (10784/15404 KB) 70%...
Uploading IDB.zip (12336/15404 KB) 80%...
Uploading IDB.zip (13872/15404 KB) 90%...
Uploaded IDB.zip 100%
Starting IDB 17.2.0.175 in port 59780...
A remote error occurred in the connected Mac
Xcode couldn't be found at /Applications/Xcode.app. Please specify the right location in Visual Studio under 'Tools > Options > Xamarin > iOS Settings' or ensure that it is installed properly at the default location ('/Applications/Xcode.app')
```

Comment: have you actually launched XCode on the Mac?  Often it needs to install additional code but only prompts to do that when its launched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into the same error - for me the solution was to open Xcode->Preferences and on the Locations tab the "Command Line Tools" field was empty. Just needed to click on the Command Line Tools drop down and select an Xcode version.
Restarted Visual Studio and reconnected and was able to connect successfully.